# TypeScript suggests literals from every index of a tuple where each index of the tuple has a unique type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Consider this unfinished snippet of code:

```
type TAnimal = 'dog' | 'cat';
type TSound = 'woof' | 'meow';
type TAnimalAndSound = [TAnimal, TSound]

const animal: TAnimalAndSound = ["dog", ]
```

When prompting intellisense with ctrl+space in VSCode, I am offered literals from all slots of the Tuple (`TAnimal` and `TSound`).

[image: problem in VSCode]

If I open the quotes, then the intellisense only offers `TSound` literals which makes me think maybe this is a VSCode problem.

**Is there a way to ensure only the correct types are suggested?**

In my project, the value can be a particular number or string, so I can't rely on opening the quotes.

Comment: The control-space suggestions can be a bit dumb. They contain a _very_ wide set of possibilities, many of which probably aren't right. As with most things having to with intellisense, you don't have very much control over it. It seems like it's offering up some ideas, but doesn't do the real type checking until you type a bit more. I'm doubtful you will get a solution here that does what you want. Just know Typescript won't let you actually use an unsafe value, even if VSCode suggests one.

Comment: @AlexWayne Man that's disappointing. You're right - if I put in one of the wrong suggestions, typescript errors. Kinda annoying cause I want to package up this thing. Guess I'll just define the allowable numbers as strings.